# Does dynamodb have maximum size limitation on query input?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I know dynamodb query has limitation on maximum response data size is 1MB. But does it have limitation on the input filter parameter? I may need to send a filter expression has a long list of values, I wonder whether it works without limtation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per AWS documentation:

The maximum length of any expression string is 4 KB, which includes ProjectionExpression, ConditionExpression, UpdateExpression, and FilterExpression.

check more details here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ServiceQuotas.html#limits-expression-parameters

hope it answer your question.